# Rails 4 How to Search by Order id or Order Status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to be able to search orders by id or by order status.
My current code is working but not 100%.

There is a has_many relationship between the Order and the Order Status models.
The order status model has four entries:
1.Processing , 2.Completed, 3.Cancelled, 4.Refunded

Example:

I have a simple form to enter the order id  and another form with a select tag
with all the Order Statuses to search by order status.

If I search for order id 1, I get all the orders with a number 1 in the id and  I also get all the orders with order status 1.

I would like get a result of either order id or order status.

**Order model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status

  def self.search(search)
    where("cast(id as text) LIKE ? OR order_status_id LIKE ? ", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

**Order Status model**

```
class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

**Orders Controller**

```
  def index
    @order_statuses = OrderStatus.all
    if params[:search]
      @orders = Order.search(params[:search])
    else
      @orders = Order.all
    end
  end
```

**Order index view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get', class:"" do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
        </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get', class:"" do %>
        <p>
            <%= select_tag :search, options_from_collection_for_select(OrderStatus.all, :id, :name, params[:search])  %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
        </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>  
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>amount</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>Last Updated</th>
        <th>manage</th>
    </tr>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
        <tr>            
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= order.total %></td>
        <td><%= order.order_status.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.updated_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'details', order %> |
            <%= link_to 'edit', edit_order_path(order) %> |
            <%= link_to 'delete', order_path(order), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I've researched the following links but I'm not finding or understanding a solution.

Links:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true

http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised?autoplay=true

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

[Rails Search Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567767/rails-search-form)

[Build static dropdown menu for simple search Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133358/build-static-dropdown-menu-for-simple-search-rails-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a search by either `order_id` or `order_status :name` attribute with the following

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status

  def self.search(query)
    query.to_s.is_i? ? where(id: query) : joins(:order_status).where('order_statuses.name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%")
  end
end
```

In order to use the `is_i?` method you will need to extend the String class by creating an initializer file to require a new `String` extension file

```
# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_extensions", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f }
```

and then create your new `String` extension file and `is_i?` method

```
# lib/core_extensions/string.rb
class String
  def is_i?
    /\A[-+]?\d+\z/ === self
  end
end
```

credit [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby#answer-1235990) for the `is_i?` method

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Can you help me understand the method a bit. The search method takes a (query) parameter. Can that be anything or it needs to be query, search or something specific  ? I'm kind of confuse about that.

Comment: the method ```search``` takes in an argument ```query``` which is a string that can either contain an ```order_id``` or some text that is in an ```order_status :name``` attribute. in order to do this the method checks whether the query is formatted like number(s) ```'123'``` and assumes if it is then it's trying to search using an ```order_id``` and if it's not and the query is more like this ```'foo'``` then it searches for ```orders``` that belong to ```order_statuses``` with the word ```'foo'``` in the ```:name``` column

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've been scratching my head with this all day.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to cast the id into text and then using like to match it. This should be enough to get what you need.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status

  def self.search(search)
    where("id = ? OR order_status_id LIKE ? ", search, "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

Comment: The cast is there because it was giving me an error in production using PG database. casting solved the problems. Thanks for your help.